# Does the Gradle javaCompile task always recompile all java classes (including unchanged?)

Tags: java, gradle

I can get an ant compile to only rebuild java classes that have changed, but I can't get Gradle to do so.

I have a project with the structure

```
root
  /src/main/java
     /pkg1/File1.java
     /pkg2/File2.java
  /build.gradle
  /build.xml (for comparing against ant)
```

File1 and File2 are not dependent on each other. File1 and File2 contain correct package information

my build.gradle file only has 1 line

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

**Ant:** When I do a `ant compile` it creates two .class files File1.class and File2.class. When I change File2.java and recompile only File2 gets rebuilt.  This is the behavior I expect?

**Gradle:** When I do a `gradle compileJava` it creates two .class files File1.class and File2.class. When I change only File2.java and recompile both File1 and File2 are rebuilt.  Why is File1 recompiled here?

Could this be due to a configuration issue? Or is it just not possible with Gradle at the moment?  Perhaps it's a bad idea to this in the first place, if so, why?

For completeness the ant file looks something like this :

```
<property name="src" location="src/main/java/"/>
<property name="build" location="build"/>

<target name="init">
  <tstamp/>
  <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source " >
  <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" includeDestClasses="true"/>
</target>
```

Comment: There's nothing inherent in Ant that compiles anything. You would need to show what ant task your have used and what options to javac you have passed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gradle doesn't support incremental Java compilation at this time. In other words, if any input of the `JavaCompile` task changes, all sources will be recompiled. I do expect incremental compilation to be supported in a future release. Until then, compile time can be improved by spreading sources over multiple source sets (which effectively means multiple compile tasks) and projects. The former helps to make up-to-date checks more effective, the latter allows for parallel compilation when running with `--parallel`.

UPDATE: Gradle now supports [incremental building](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#incremental_build) since 2015.

Comment: I think this was added in gradle 2.1 in that the release notes suggest it exists -- I can't get it to work though so not going to suggest a new edit or anything on the answer

Comment: That's correct. Incremental Java compilation is still an incubating feature, but it gets better with every release.

Comment: Yep, I'm very much looking forward to it being more stable :)

Comment: Though it is a bit old post but I would like to share who comes for searching like me. Referincing to this location , now gradle supports Incremental Java Compilation.  https://docs.gradle.org/2.1/release-notes#incremental-java-compilation

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. Still answering for letting people know about this great and wonderful feature.

The incremental task for gradle is in incubation stage.

Please go through:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#incremental_tasks
- http://gradle.org/feature-spotlight-incremental-builds/
- https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs.html